# Line in text file is evaluated multiple times?

Tags: c, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I need to convert infix to postfix and evaluate postfix expression. When reading from a file, I should be able to evaluate multiple expressions at once. But when I run it and it encounters an expression that is not well-formed in the sense that there are more closed parentheses than open ones, it evaluates that expression 2 or 3 times.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000


typedef struct stack
{
    int data[MAX];
    int top;
} stack;



int priority(char);
void init(stack*);
int empty(stack*);
int full(stack*);
char pop(stack*);
void push(stack*, char);
char top(stack*);
void add(char*, char, int);
void keyboard();
void read_file();
int change(char);
void pushYO(double);
double popYO();


stack s;
char x;
int i, token, topYO = -1;
double result[MAX];

char filepath[MAX];

int main()
{
    char choice;
    init(&s);
    system("CLS");
    printf("[1] Keyboard \n[2] Read from text file \n[3] Exit \n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    if(choice != '1' && choice != '2' && choice != '3')
    {
        main();
    }
    else if(choice == '1')
    {
        keyboard();
    }
    else if(choice == '2')
    {
        read_file();
    }
    else if(choice == '3')
    {
        printf("\nThank you for using Kei Shirabe's \ninfix to postfix converter and evaluator! :)\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}


void keyboard() //the keyboard input version. this works fine
{
//code here
}


void read_file()
{
    int z, count, form, paren;
    double one, two, three = 1;
    char infx[MAX];
    char pofx[MAX];
    char choice;
    FILE *text = fopen("text.txt", "a");
    printf("Enter path of file:");
    scanf("%s",&filepath);
    FILE *textYO = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if((textYO) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError! Unable to open %s\n\n", filepath);
    }
    else
    {

        while((fgets(infx, MAX, textYO))!= NULL)
        {
            form = -1, paren = 0, count = 0, z = 0;
            infx[
            strlen(infx)-1] = '\0';


        for (i=0; i<strlen(infx); i++)
        {
            if((token = infx[i]) != '\n')
            {
                if(isalnum(token))
                {
                    form++;
                }
                else
                {

                    if(token == '(')
                    {
                        paren++;

                    }
                    else if(token == ')')
                    {
                        paren--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        form--;
                    }

                }

                if (paren < 0)
                {
                    printf("%s", infx);
                    fprintf(text, "%s", infx);
                    printf("\n\nError! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n");
                    fprintf(text, "\n\nError! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n");
                }
                else
                if(isalnum(token))
                {
                    add(pofx, token, count);
                    count++;
                }
                else
                if(token == '(')
                   {
                        push(&s, '(');
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       if(token == ')')
                       while((x = pop(&s)) != '(')
                             {
                                 add(pofx, x, count);
                                 count++;
                             }

                             else
                             if(token == '^')
                             {
                                 push(&s, token);
                             }
                             else

                             {
                                 while(priority(token) <= priority(top(&s)) && !empty(&s))
                                 {
                                     x = pop(&s);
                                     add(pofx, x, count);
                                     count++;
                                 }
                                 push(&s, token);
                             }
                    }
            }
            else
            {
            while(!empty(&s))
            {
                x = pop(&s);
                add(pofx, x, count);
                count++;
            }
            }
        }

        if(form != 0 || paren != 0)
        {
            printf("%s", infx);
            fprintf(text, "%s", infx);
            printf("\n\nError! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n");
            fprintf(text, "\n\nError! Not well formed :( \n-----------------\n");
        }
        else
        {
            form = -1, paren = 0;
            printf("%s", infx);
            fprintf(text, "%s", infx);
            printf("\n\nPostfix: %s \n\n", pofx);
            fprintf(text, "\n\nPostfix: %s\n\n", pofx);

            while((token = pofx[z++]) != '\0')
            {
                three = 1;
                if(!isdigit(token) && !isalpha(token))
                {
                    two = popYO();
                    one = popYO();

                    switch(token)
                    {
                        case '+':
                        pushYO(one+two); break;
                        case '-':
                        pushYO(one-two); break;
                        case '*':
                        pushYO(one*two); break;
                        case '/':
                        pushYO(one/two); break;
                        case '^':
                        if (two > 0)
                        {
                        for(i=0;i<two;i++)
                        {
                            three = three * one;
                        }
                        pushYO(three);
                        three = 1; break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        for(i=0;i<(two-(2*two));i++)
                        {
                            three = three * one;
                        }
                        pushYO((1/three));
                        three = 1; break;
                        }
                        }
                    }


                else if(isalpha(token))
                {
                    if(isupper(token))
                    {
                        pushYO(token - '@');
                    }

                    if(islower(token))
                    {
                        pushYO(token - change(token));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    pushYO(token - '0');
                }
            }

            printf("Result: %lf\n-----------------\n", result[topYO]);
            fprintf(text, "Result: %lf\n-----------------\n", result[topYO]);

        }


    }

        }

        fclose(text);
        fclose(textYO);
        printf("\nRun again? \n[1] Yes \n[any other key] No\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        if(choice == '1')
        {
            main();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThank you for using Kei Shirabe's \ninfix to postfix converter and evaluator! :)\n");
            exit(0);
        }
}


//other functions down here, not important
```

Sample text file (and yes there is an extra space at the end):

```
(1+2)) 
(1+2*3)
```

For this text file, the expression `(1+2))` is evaluated three times, each result being "Not well formed". The last expression works as expected.

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger, or adding a few extra printouts, to see which paths it's running through and why? Have you tried manually stepping through the code, "playing computer", to understand what it will do with this input? Any of those is a good way to start debugging it.

Comment: Why not write a function to filter out "Not well formed" expressions and correct them?  Count open parens and close parens and drop as necessary.  Then you're only working with well formed data.

Comment: @keshlam yes i've done that and i've made some changes to the code, but the same problem always comes up - multiple evaluation of the line

Comment: @JB0x2D1 the program is supposed to be able to detect Not well formed expressions and print an error message if so. No need to correct/evaluate them

Comment: OK, since you've debugged: Multiple evaluation of which of the several lines? (My own inclination, for what it's worth, would be to have the ill-formed expression throw an exception, immediately stopping interpretation of the expression, and have the main program catch that exception. That doesn't fix your bug -- which I presume is a problem in how you're backing out of the interpreter recursions -- but it sweeps the problem under the rug.)

Comment: I would still split off various tests and operations into separate functions that you could debug individually. Then your `read_file()` would only read lines and call a series of other functions. I think you'll find this approach much easier to troubleshoot/debug because you're breaking the problem down into smaller problems.  Isolating the fault to a smaller function is much easier than trying to find the bug in a large if else if chain. It is also much easier for everybody to read.